# How to run a macro in a password protected workbook from another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am using an .xlsm file developed by someone else. 
I need to run the macro called SimulateHouse, however the .xlsm file is password protected and I can't access any information regarding the code.

Is there anyway I can run this macro from other workbooks?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the password then you can't do this.

If you do know the password then you can open the workbook (you can do that in VBA too) and use `Application.Run` passing the function name fully desciminated by the name of the workbook.